# Total number density of galaxies and problematic expression in practise

Tags: galaxy, astrophysics, cosmology, galaxy-cluster

This post comes from physics exchange forum, I have transfered it here, maybe I will be luckier since I have not received answers on the other forum.

Here is the issue :

I am asked to give the formal expression of the **total number density of galaxies** and explain **why is this expression problematic in practice**.

From what I saw from my research and into my lectures, I have found the follwing relation which gives the number of galaxies $N$ with magnitude $(m < M)$ (number counts) :

$\text{log}\,N(m<M)\,\propto\,0.6 M + \text{constant}\quad(1)$

$N(m<M)\,\propto\,\text{exp}(0.6 M)\,\text{exp(constant)}\quad(2)$

I don't know what the teacher wants to highlight, i.e by saying that the formal expression of the total number density of galaxies is problematic in practice, given that I even haven't the kind of expression or equation which gives the estimation of galaxy density.

**1) Concerning this distribution to use, do you advise me to use a distribution as a function of magnitude, mass or a distribution as function of luminosity (like Schechter) ?**

**2) I have seen on web the HMF (Halo Mass function) but it seems to be about the dark matter halos : can we count one dark matter halo per galaxy ?**

**3) But the problem is here is that a dark matter halo is more massive than the galaxy hosted in this halo : how can we deal with this ?**

If someone could help me, this would be kind.

**PS:** **I have also to explain why the estimation of galaxies density is difficult and problematic**.

**4) What are the issues when we want to estimate density of galaxies ?**

Concerning the distribution as a function of luminosity, I have found the **Schechter luminosity function** :

$$N(L)\ \mathrm {d} L=\phi^{*}\left({\frac{L}{L^{*}}}\right)^{\alpha}\mathrm {e}^{-L/L^{*}}{\frac{\mathrm {d} L}{L^{*}}}$$

**UPDATE 1:** my apologies, $m$ and $M$ represent apparent magnitude and not masses.

But the questions remain about the counting of galaxies and the computation of total density at large scale.

**In practise, what are the major problems when we want to estimate this density ?**

**UPDATE 2:** people here not really motivated by this bounty ... feel free to ask for precisions about this post .

For the moment, I am faced to know at which scale I can compute a mean density : have I got to take into account this scale since it seems to have a dependance between density and volume considered, doesn't it ?

**Is there a general formula to express this dependance ?**

Regards

Comment: The problem with the form "N(m<M)" is that you have to define when a clump is so small that you no longer consider it a galaxy. Usually one considers N(m>M), since the number density decreases rapidly with halo mass / galaxy mass. I don't know where you got Eqs. 1 & 2 from, but usually one is interested in a _average_ number _density_, not an absolute number, unless you're talking specifically about some particular cluster or whatever. I think you'll find the answers in the links I give below to other astro.SE posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number Density of Dark Matter Halos](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27694/5264), [Number of galaxies per redshift](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13072/5264), and [How many galaxies are there in the Hercules–Corona Borealis Great Wall?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/8903/5264). See also [Boötes Void numbers, 2016](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16132/5264)

Comment: -@pela . Thanks for your quick answer. For the moment, I have found the Schechter Luminosity function. I still try to find out what are the main problems where one wants to estimate the density of galaxies : I have proposed different hypothesis into my **UPDATE 1** : feel free to tell me if you think these issues prevent a good estimation for this density of galaxies in universe, or if you know relevant criteria which make things harder to calculate. regards